# Density of Schwartz functions in $L^2$ on a compact domain

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

I'm trying to prove that the space $AC^2([0,1])$ of absolutely continuous, complex-valued functions defined on $[0,1]$, with the property that their derivatives are in $L^2([0,1])$ is dense in $L^2([0,1])$.

My idea for the proof is to show that $\mathcal{S}([0,1]) \subset AC^2[(0,1)]$, where $\mathcal{S}([0,1])$ is the Schwartz space and use the fact that it's dense in $L^2$.

But I only know that $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So my question is: is this set still dense in $L^2$ after changing the domain to a compact set? Moreover, is this the correct reasoning to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: What is $\mathcal{S}([0,1])$?  Schwartz space is only defined for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami But there is no "the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}([0,1])$".  There are Schwartz-Bruhat space on $\mathbb{T}$ but that is a stretch.

Comment: Touché. I haven't thought about test functions in decades.

Comment: Thank you. In this case can you give me some hint on how to prove the claim? Could I maybe use smooth compaclty supported functions instead?

Comment: @keithjones yes that works instead.

Comment: The polynomials are dense.